# How does one sign up for an EOS account on the premium .com name?

Tags: accounts, premium, namespace

Who purchased the .com premium name? And how can one sign up for a .com account name?

Answer (score 2):

The `com` namespace appears to have been bought by StartEOS as they're the parent of the [`com`](https://eosflare.io/account/com) account. They paid [150,000 EOS on 2018-07-06](https://eospark.com/MainNet/tx/1a0dfb64795e889c53cc7132fc73c2e2aa47bcc9938391b7db869686b518dab9) for the namespace.

To buy an account name under their namespace, they recommend using their mobile wallet software, which provides an option to do it.

You can see what account names were created under the `.com` namespace by checking the transactions from [`com`](https://eosflare.io/account/com)

Familiar names that have already been created include:

- bitmain.com
- okex.com
- binance.com
- antpool.com
- google.com
- eosfinex.com